# specific Order by Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

Is possible to order on Linq according to a specific order?
something like

```
List<bbHeader> bb = new List<bbHeader>();
bb.OrderBy(x => x.Country.CompareTo(new string[]{"AR","CL","PY","UY","AUP"}));
```

The idea is that the Country field is ordered according to the specific order of the string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a very direct way in your example:

```
var sequence = new [] { "AR", "CL", "PY", "UY", "AUP" };

List<bbHeader> bb = new List<bbHeadher>();

// fill bb

// takes the item, checks the index of the country in the array
var result = bb.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(sequence, x.Country));
```

In this way, you are ordering by the index Country is found in the sequence string.  Just keep in mind that not-found items will be -1, which you can correct for also if you like.

If you want to do anything more complex, you can to create your own custom `IComparer` class implementation to compare the items using your custom order.  This can then be passed into OrderBy.

Such an IComparer would look like:

```
public sealed class SequenceComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private string[] _sequence { get; set; }

    public SequenceComparer(string[] sequence)
    {
        if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");

        _sequence = sequence;
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return 0;

        return Array.IndexOf(_sequence, x).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(_sequence, y));
    }
}
```

And can be called like:

```
var result = bb.OrderBy(x => x.Country, new SequenceComparer(new [] { "AR", "CL", "PY", "UY", "AUP" }));
```

Either way works well, the latter is nice and reusable, but the former (using IndexOf directly) is still very concise as well.  Your choice.

Comment: @Guillermo: just edited my example, though of a very direct way using Array.IndexOf()

Comment: Great, I've been very helpful

Comment: +1 for the `Array.IndexOf` trick. I wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: @rally25rs: Yep, IndexOf() is a direct member of `List<T>`, but not `T[]`.  Would be easy to create an extension method for it though...

Comment: You mention that not found items would be -1, but could correct for that. How would you do that? Because my 'sorted' list now has the ones I'm interested in at the bottom instead of the top.

Comment: I think i just answered my own question. What i did in my example is set when it evaluates to -1, then set it to a greater number in the sequence. For example: .OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(sequence, x.Country) == -1 ? 99 : Array.IndexOf(sequence, x.Country))

Answer (score 1):

well you can pass in your own delegate to orderby function and the comparison logic in that case can be defined by you.